# Windows 7 and Mint Linux separated disks no boot?

Tags: windows-7, linux-mint

I have installed windows 7 on disk 1 and then installed mint linux on disk 2

After a reboot it says that can-t find the device and appear grub-recover or something like that...

I`m noob so I would like someone to help how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Don`t know if it helps buts here is the fdisk

```
Disk /dev/sda: 100.0 GB, 100030242816 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 12161 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000caf74

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              13       12162    97581056    7  HPFS/NTFS

Disk /dev/sdb: 100.0 GB, 100030242816 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 12161 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0007ab7c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       11662    93667328   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2           11662       12162     4016129    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5           11662       12162     4016128   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 4029 MB, 4029677568 bytes
128 heads, 63 sectors/track, 976 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8064 * 512 = 4128768 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1               2         976     3931136    b  W95 FAT32
```

Comment: you can edit this information into your own answer. Answers are for answers, not adding information into your question. You should be able to edit your own answers no matter your rep.